# Linux Libertine Bold Math

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, bold, libertine

I'm using Linux Libertine everywhere in my document. However, I cannot figure out how to get bold math `\mathbf` to display as bold text. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11643/4071) seemed related to this problem, but trying that (replacing Minion Pro with Linux Libertine O) in my case gives me the following error (for every `X:Y:Z`):

> Symbol font `Latin:m:n' not defined.

How can I get bold math symbols in my document?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathspec, libertine, lipsum}
\setmathsfont[ItalicFont={LinLibertine_RI.otf}]{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\setmathrm{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\setboldmathrm{LinLibertine_RB.otf}
\setmathsf{LinBiolinum_RB.otf}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation}
    \hat{Q}_i=\int_0^\infty \mathcal{G}^2(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}(x^2) f_i(x)dx
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: P.S. Although I couldn't reproduce in this MWE, my actual document also throws a "Too many math alphabets used in version normal" error when I try to use `\mathbf`. I've cleaned up all redundant packages per [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3676/4071) and answer, but the problem still persists...

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't get the error you claim, but some things go wrong, I believe because of how `libertine` interacts with `mathspec`.

One has to specify the classes for which Libertine is wanted, though, and this triggers the error about insufficient mathgroups. This can be cured with the method outlined in `http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100428/4427`

This version works, by directly calling the fonts by name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100426/
%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100428/
\def\new@mathgroup{\alloc@8\mathgroup\mathchardef\@cclvi}
\patchcmd{\document@select@group}{\sixt@@n}{\@cclvi}{}{}
\patchcmd{\select@group}{\sixt@@n}{\@cclvi}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathspec,lipsum}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Linux Libertine O}
\setmathrm{Linux Libertine O}
\setboldmathrm{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathsf{Linux Biolinum O}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{gather}
\hat{Q}_i=\int_0^\infty \mathcal{G}^2(\mathbf{x})
  \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}(x^2) f_i(x)\,dx=\mathsf{X} \\
\hat{Q}_i=\int_0^\infty \mathcal{G}^2(\mathbf{x})
  \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}("x^2) f_i(x)\,dx=\mathsf{X}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

I added a line to your formula, showing how `"` is necessary as explained in the `mathspec` manual.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! A followup question (I can ask a new one if necessary): If you add `mathrsfs` for script math, everything changes to funky and weird symbols (possibly something is being redefined) and the symbols change depending on where it is placed in the preamble. Is it because I have not explicitly defined the font to be substituted for script math?

Comment: @yoda If I add `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` (no matter where), then `$\mathscr{A}$` does what's expected and I see no other change.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I also had a `bm`, which in conjunction with `mathrsfs` is what's causing trouble (just `bm` by itself or `mathrsfs` by itself are fine). With these, I get http://i.stack.imgur.com/TgKoY.png for the MWE above. I'll try and figure out a way without using `bm` (FWIW, I'm stitching together 5 different LaTeX documents written at different points in time and for different journals into a single manuscript, so they all have some custom stuff that interferes with another)